# Expo Camera Crashes with onFacesDetected option on (Android custom dev client )

Tags: expo

expo app keeps crashing whenever I navigated to the camera component. am using expo sdk 43, and this happens on expo custom dev client only but works fine with expo go app.

```
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import * as FaceDetector from "expo-face-detector";

export default app = ()=>{
  const handleFaceDetection = ({faces}) => console.log(faces);
  return <Camera
              style={styles.camera}
              type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
              onFacesDetected={handleFaceDetection}
              faceDetectorSettings={{
                mode: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorMode.fast,
                detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorLandmarks.none,
                runClassifications:
                  FaceDetector.FaceDetectorClassifications.none,
                minDetectionInterval: 500,
                tracking: true,
              }}
         />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a Native dependency to your project, you have to re-build your `dev-client`:

```bash
eas build --platform android --profile development
```

It works fine in "Expo Go" because the whole Expo SDK is already bundled inside the app.